# XCode 6 stepping into IF statement when condition is false

Tags: ios, xcode6

When I'm debugging, I notice that the debugger is entering an IF Statement when the conditional logic is FALSE.

[image]

You can see in the debug area that `foundCharacters` is not empty but `parentElement` DOES NOT match the string "item." So why is Xcode hitting that line of code?  When I attempt to step into the next line, the code doesn't actually execute and the debugger jumps back up to the IF statement. Why is Xcode doing this?  I wasted an hour on this.

Comment: you should never compare strings with '=='. you can use `.equals` for it

Comment: The SWIFT documentation says "String and character equality is checked with the “equal to” operator (==) and the “not equal to” operator (!=), as described in Comparison Operators: "

Answer (score 1):

Try isEqualToString.

Using "==" returns true if two objects have the same memory address. What is appears you are trying to do is checking if two Strings are functionally equivalent.

NSHipster has a great article on testing for equality here: http://nshipster.com/equality/

EDIT: This only applies to Objective-C. Apparently Swift is the opposite.

Comment: Is there a solution in Swift?

Comment: My answer is only true of Objective-C. AFAIK this shouldn't be happening as described by your question in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

For length check you can use `yourString.length`

And for the equality you need to use `[yourString isEqualToString:@"Valuetobecompared"]`

Answer (score 0):

to use `"=="` fine in swift But i doubt it is really going in `if` part, it might be part of stepping while compilation. Try to print something in if part to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was comparing if the string was not empty then do something but for some reason Xcode was stepping into if success block even when the string was empty or nil.

A clean build, deleting the derived data and reinstalling the app on my simulator did the trick for me.